# Reverse geocoding with python to get googlemaps url

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns df['latitude'] and df['longitude'] and I am trying to reverse geocode them into full address google maps in df['Address']. However, I am not very successful. Is there a better way of doing this? I am using Geocoder package.

This is a sample from dataframe

\\
lat, lon
48.7082,2.2797
48.7577,2.2188
47.8333,2.2500
48.9833,1.7333
47.9333,1.9181
46.2735,4.2586
\\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the google maps API . You will need to use python 3.5 or higher and need to get a service key. You can get a API key using cloud console . There are wrappers out there that should make your job easier.

[Google  Maps API for client services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python)

[Wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/googlemaps/)

Answer (score 0):

First set your api key for google maps access:

```
export GOOGLE_API_KEY=<Secret API Key>
export GOOGLE_CLIENT=<Secret Client>
export GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=<Secret Client Secret>
```

Then execute the following code to use "reverse" geocoding to create a location from a set of lat lon coordinates:

```
import geocoder
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'lat':48.7082, 'lon':2.2797}, {'lat':48.7577,'lon':2.2188})

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    g = geocoder.google([row['lat'], row['lon']], method='reverse')
    print(g.json)
```